# Send HTML Email from PHP Mail function

Tags: php, html, html-email

I have simple code here,

But couldn't able to make it work. Is there any other way.?

It's sends HTML coding in email rather then table.

Is there another way to do so.?

OR How Do I create csv or excel and attached with email it self automatically.?

```
$to = "beback@gmail.com";
$subject = 'New Employee file';

$message = "<html>
        <head>
        <title>New Employee</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p>Here IS the New Employee List</p>
        <table border=1>
        <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>POSNum</th>
        <th>POSPassword</th>
        <th>location</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>";

 $table = "send_payroll"; // Enter Your Table Name 
 $sql = mysql_query("select           last_name,
                                  first_name,
                                  pos_num,
                                  pos_password,
                                  store
                                  from $table");
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$message .="<tr>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$message .='<td>'.$row["$i"].'</td>';
}
$message .="</tr>";
}
$message .="</tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html> ";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: Nirav <be.gmail.com>\r\n";

 echo "$message" ; //Display table correctly

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: `be.gmail.com` is this email-adress correct?
Please add what isn't working. Errors?

Comment: No error nothing , I changed that email address original email is different , I received an email but with html code.

Comment: Or be.gemail.com is correct does not matter. It is just an header!

Comment: I tested your script on my server and it works fine for me. I also use an gmail address. Can you check the received headers (is content-type etc. set)?

Comment: Do I need to set .php file with specific Encoding.?

Comment: @back123 the encoding of the PHP file has nothing to do with your issue. Could you please check & post the headers of your received mail as mentioned before?

Comment: MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to your comment that the incoming mail has the content-type text/plain I assume the problem comes with your local mail server configuration. Also a firewall may block or overwrite the outgoing headers.

Try sending an email with a class like [PHPMail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). For testing you can use the SMTP server from gmail.